# Валидация в форме имени, фамилии и возраста

Tags: javascript, валидация

Есть форма валидации. Имя и фамилия должны быть без пробелов, с большой буквы и минимум две буквы, а для возраста задать интервал от 18 до 100. Как это сделать?

```js
let form = document.querySelector('.formWithValidation');
let validateBtn = form.querySelector('.validateBtn');
let form_name = form.querySelector('.form_name');
let form_surname = form.querySelector('.form_surname');
let form_age = form.querySelector('.form_age');
let form_email = form.querySelector('.form_email');
let fields = form.querySelectorAll('.field')


form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  let errors = form.querySelectorAll('.error')
  for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    errors[i].remove()
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (!fields[i].value) {
      console.log('Поле нужно обязательно заполнить!', fields[i])
      let error = document.createElement('div')
      error.className = 'error'
      error.style.color = 'red'
      error.innerHTML = 'Поле нужно обязательно заполнить!'
      form[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, fields[i])

    }
  }

  console.log('clicked on validate')
  console.log('form_name: ', form_name.value)
  console.log('form_surname: ', form_surname)
  console.log('form_age: ', form_age.value)
  console.log('form_email: ', form_email.value)
})
```

```css
input {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class='formWithValidation'>
  <div>
    <label for='form_fname'>Имя: </label>
    <input type='text' class='form_name field' name='first_name'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='form_surname'>Фамилия: </label>
    <input type='text' class='form_surname field' name='second_name'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='form_age'>Возраст: </label>
    <input type='text' class='form_age field' name='age'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='form_email'>Email: </label>
    <input type='email' class='form_email field' name='email'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" class="validateBtn" value='Submit'>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Китайцы и испанцы вас проклянут

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/

Answer (score 3):

По хорошему бы конечно ещё и почту проверять ...

```js
let form = document.querySelector('.formWithValidation');
let validateBtn = form.querySelector('.validateBtn');
let form_name = form.querySelector('.form_name');
let form_surname = form.querySelector('.form_surname');
let form_age = form.querySelector('.form_age');
let form_email = form.querySelector('.form_email');
let fields = form.querySelectorAll('.field');


/**
 * Собственно функция которая принимает input,
 * а потом выбирает тип валидации в зависимости от атрибута data-validationType этого инпута.
 * Дальше дело техники - какой паттерн подобрать, в задаче спрашивается про возраст и имя ...
 * Возвращает булевое значение.
 */
const validation = input => {
  const val = input.value;

  switch(input.dataset.validationtype) {
    case 'name': return /^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+$/.test(val);
    case 'age' : return parseInt(val) >= 18 && parseInt(val) <= 100;
    default    : return val !== '';
  }
}


form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()

   let errors = form.querySelectorAll('.error')
   for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    errors[i].remove()
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (!validation(fields[i])) {
      console.log('Поле нужно обязательно заполнить!', fields[i])
      let error = document.createElement('div')
      error.className='error'
      error.style.color = 'red'
      error.innerHTML = 'Поле нужно обязательно заполнить!'
      form[i].parentElement.insertBefore(error, fields[i])
    }
  }

  console.log('clicked on validate')
  console.log('form_name: ', form_name.value)
  console.log('form_surname: ', form_surname)
  console.log('form_age: ', form_age.value)
  console.log('form_email: ', form_email.value)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  input{
   margin-top: 10px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<form class='formWithValidation'>

  <div>
   <label for='form_fname'>Имя: </label>
      <input type='text' class='form_name field' name='first_name' data-validationType="name">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for='form_surname'>Фамилия: </label>
      <input type='text' class='form_surname field' name='second_name' data-validationType="name">
  </div>

  <div>
   <label for='form_age'>Возраст: </label>
   <input type='text' class='form_age field' name='age' data-validationType="age">
  </div>


  <div>
   <label for='form_email'>Email: </label>
   <input type='email' class='form_email field' name='email'>
  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="submit" class="validateBtn" value='Submit'>
  </div>

</form>


 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так а разве оно не автоматически проверяет почту? У меня он запрашивает на то, чтобы в почте был "@"?

Comment: @Matc, Проверяет автоматически, но разное поведение для однотипных полей - не очень правильное решение с точки зрения UI.

Comment: Я понял, а можно без регулярного выражения проверить его на правильность?

Comment: @Matc, нет. Можете взять регулярку [ОТСЮДА](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-an-email-address-be-validated-in-javascript).

Comment: Да у меня есть регулярное для его проверки, просто думал, что есть другой способ. Спасибо